# Array not updating values in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, equation

So I have the following code in MATLAB that implements a differences equation. However the entries of the array not seem to be updated at every iteration. I don't know how such a simple thing is getting messed up, probably it is a silly mistake. Here is the code:

```
K12=0.3*3600; 
K21=0.2455*3600;
K10=0.0643*3600; 
V1=3110;
V2=3110; 
delta=1000; 
h=1;
n_zeros=5; 
val_dose=3;
n_doses=10;

n_dias=n_doses+n_doses*n_zeros;

vec_doses=val_dose*ones(1, n_doses); 

vec_doses=upsample(vec_doses, n_zeros+1);

t=zeros(1, n_dias); 
c1=zeros(1, n_dias*h);
c2=zeros(1, n_dias*h);

c1(1*h)=0; 
c2(1*h)=0; 

A1=(-K12-K10)/V1;
B1=K21/V1; 
D1=delta/V1;
A2=K12/V2; 
B2=-K21/V2; 

for k=1:(n_dias-1)
    
    t(k+1)=k; 

    c1((k+1)*h)=c1(k*h)+h*A1*c1(k*h)+h*B1*c2(k*h)+h*D1*vec_doses(k);
    c1((k+1)*h)=c2(k*h)+h*A2*c1(k*h)+h*B2*c2(k*h);
    
end
```

And after this both c1 and c2 are arrays of just zeros, just like when they are initiazed. Any guess?

Comment: Math don't lie... You may use the debugger, iterate the loop step by step, and see that all the values are zeros. It could be that you want to replace `c1((k+1)*h)=c2(k*h)+h*A2*c1(k*h)+h*B2*c2(k*h);` with `c2((k+1)*h)=c2(k*h)+h*A2*c1(k*h)+h*B2*c2(k*h);`

Comment: You never assign anything to `c2`.